# Paginate category by posts in django

Tags: django, pagination, django-class-based-views

I've got a blog system, with categories and posts, as shown simplified below.

I want to have a detail page for category, where I paginate the posts belonging to that category.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField()

class Post(models.Model):   
    title = models.CharField(max_length=90)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name="posts")
```

I use django 1.4 and class based views. What is the correct way of doing this? I guess I need to use `paginate_queryset(queryset, page_size)`, but I don't know how. This is my basis for the view:

```
class CategoryDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Category
    queryset = object.posts.all()

    def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, page_size):
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/pagination/). It should help to get you started.

Comment: Yes, I know how to use the Paginator-constructor, I'm asking how to use [paginate_queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/class-based-views/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.paginate_queryset), which is part of the Class Based Generic Views